# LsaOpenPolicy, LsaAddAccountRights with POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT access mask

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using the LsaAddAccountRights function to assign SE_SERVICE_LOGIN_RIGHT to specified local machine/domain accounts during installation of my service.

During the call to LsaOpenPolicy I pass both flags POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT and POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES as parts of the access mask - and all things are working great.

I am just worried about having POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT as one of the flags, as the function [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for LsaAddAccountRights reads:

> The LsaAddAccountRights function assigns one or more privileges to an
>   account. If the account does not exist, LsaAddAccountRights **creates**
>   it.

I am unclear in which context this account gets created.

When I do not add POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT access as part of the access flags to LsaOpenPolicy I can not add SE_SERVICE_LOGIN_RIGHT to an existing account - hence I need to add this flag.

I don't want to be somehow adding accounts when the user misspells the account name.

Comment: It doesn't mean that it creates a completely new account, it means that it adds the account to the policy database.  But I don't have a reference to hand to prove it.

Comment: Where did the SID come from? If you just make up a valid SID, then it definitely adds a new account to the policy database. But `LsaLookupSids` should fail. You can remove the account via `LsaOpenAccount` followed by `LsaDelete`.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, the lookup for the SID does fail for unknown accounts, which is why I have been able to get away with my current solution. I don't like coding with assumptions which is why I just want to make sure what POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT actually does :)

Comment: But you say you don't want to add accounts when the user misspells the account name. Are you expecting the user to provide a string SID instead of an account name? I don't know why you wouldn't use Win32 `LookupAccountSid` or `LsaLookupSids`.

Comment: Come to think of it, since the arguments to LsaAddAccountRights don't include a username, there's no way it could create a new account.  But in any case as @eryksun points out you presumably have to look up the SID first anyway, so if the username has been mistyped you'll find out *before* you call LsaAddAccountRights.